# The import java.awt cannot be resolved

Tags: java, awt, java-10

I have installed the Eclipse [Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)] and JDK 10 on a MacBookPro with macOS 10.13.5
 When I write in my code: `import java.awt.*;`

I get the error:

> The import java.awt cannot be resolved

Is the `java.awt` included in JDK 10 ? If yes where is and how can I make visible to Eclipse? If no how can I add java.awt?

Comment: Have you added that your project requires the module for awt?

Comment: From Java 9 onwards, Java is modularized. awt is 99% useless in Java apps and is therefore in a separate module (java.desktop) that is not loaded by default. You must explicitly tell Java to include this module.

Comment: I think the java.awt is included in JDK10, so I add only the line: import java.awt.* in my code. How can I tell to JDK to include java.awt ?

Comment: @Livio it is included in JDK10 but is not loaded when starting the JVM or seen by the compiler except if you explicitly ask for it. That's why this package is not found.

Comment: How can I ask to the compiler to load java.awt?
Sorry for the obvious question but is the first day I use SDK and Eclipse.
Thank you

Comment: @Livio I don't know (that's why I did not post an answer). But I think that this link is a good start : http://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity

Comment: In Eclipse - Package Explorer  I can see JRE System Library - java.desktop - java.awt but the error is still there.

Comment: @Livio do you use modules? If yes you must declare `requires java.desktop;` inside your modules.java

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> Is the `java.awt` included in JDK 10?

Ye, the package does exist. [The Java10 API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html) do confirm the same as well.

> If yes where is and how can I make visible to Eclipse?

In a modular code, all you need to do, is to [resolve the `java.desktop` module](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java.desktop-summary.html) by declaring a dependency on it in your module-descriptor file(`module-info.java`). i.e.

```
requires java.desktop;
```

Comment: I wish Eclipse's "Quick fix" would help out here... Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @Naman, Could you please share in detail where to put it?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, just add this **maven build compiler plugin** portion to your main project Maven POM.xml 
 to specify which JDK9+ modules **MUST BE** added for **javac** compilation purposes.

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    ...
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        ...
    </properties>

    ...

    <build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>

                    <!-- JDK9+ Add Module MAGIC happens below...          -->
                    <!-- Add implicit default JDK9+ java.se explicitly    -->
                    <!-- Add explicit java.desktop for import java.awt.*; -->
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--add-modules</arg>
                        <arg>java.se,java.desktop</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

  </project>
```

as explained here:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity

For other common missing JDK10+ modules, please refer to:

[http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/10/pfd/java-se-10-pfd-spec-01/api/overview-summary.html](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/10/pfd/java-se-10-pfd-spec-01/api/overview-summary.html)