# Is `sun.awt.image` package deprecated?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system, module-info

I wanted to use some codes that using `sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder` in my project. The problem is source code is based on **Java 8** and my project using **JDK 9+** (11). So I got this error:

> Package '`sun.awt.image`' is declared in module '`java.desktop`', which does not export it to *the unnamed module*.

for `import sun.awt.image.*`, and:

> Symbol is declared in module '`java.desktop`' which does not export package '`sun.awt.image`'

for using `PNGImageDecoder` or `ImageDecoder` etc.

After some efforts to find a solution, I found some similar situations that suggest adding `requires java.desktop;` to `module-info.java` file (like [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503140/the-import-java-awt-cannot-be-resolved) and [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42576762/5318303)). But as I realized this solution can only be useful when your project already has a `module-info.java` file and you missing one used module in it.

My project hadn't this file already (pay attention to "*the unnamed module*" in the first error message). As far as I know, this means all modules are imported automatically. So adding this file and adding that line hadn't any effect except (changing error message and) causing some similar issues for other parts of my codes (which were, of course, solvable by adding required modules to `module-info.java` file).

To sure I imported all modules in `jmods` folder (of JDK 11), but the problem didn't solve:

```
requires java.base;
requires java.compiler;
requires java.datatransfer;
requires java.desktop;
requires java.instrument;
requires java.logging;
requires java.management;
requires java.management.rmi;
requires java.naming;
requires java.net.http;
requires java.prefs;
requires java.rmi;
requires java.scripting;
requires java.se;
requires java.security.jgss;
requires java.security.sasl;
requires java.smartcardio;
requires java.sql;
requires java.sql.rowset;
requires java.transaction.xa;
requires java.xml.crypto;
requires java.xml;
requires jdk.accessibility;
requires jdk.aot;
requires jdk.attach;
requires jdk.charsets;
requires jdk.compiler;
requires jdk.crypto.cryptoki;
requires jdk.crypto.ec;
requires jdk.crypto.mscapi;
requires jdk.dynalink;
requires jdk.editpad;
requires jdk.hotspot.agent;
requires jdk.httpserver;
requires jdk.internal.ed;
requires jdk.internal.jvmstat;
requires jdk.internal.le;
requires jdk.internal.opt;
requires jdk.internal.vm.ci;
requires jdk.internal.vm.compiler;
requires jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management;
requires jdk.jartool;
requires jdk.javadoc;
requires jdk.jcmd;
requires jdk.jconsole;
requires jdk.jdeps;
requires jdk.jdi;
requires jdk.jdwp.agent;
requires jdk.jfr;
requires jdk.jlink;
requires jdk.jshell;
requires jdk.jsobject;
requires jdk.jstatd;
requires jdk.localedata;
requires jdk.management.agent;
requires jdk.management.jfr;
requires jdk.management;
requires jdk.naming.dns;
requires jdk.naming.rmi;
requires jdk.net;
requires jdk.pack;
requires jdk.rmic;
requires jdk.scripting.nashorn;
requires jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell;
requires jdk.sctp;
requires jdk.security.auth;
requires jdk.security.jgss;
requires jdk.unsupported.desktop;
requires jdk.unsupported;
requires jdk.xml.dom;
requires jdk.zipfs;
```

---

I know this package (`sun.awt.image`) exists in `java.desktop` module (of JDK 11), but don't know how can access it.

I use IntelliJ IDEA as IDE.

Comment: You should not use `sun.*` or `com.sun.*` classes in your program; they are undocumented, internal classes of the JDK and can change in any release. Using them possibly makes your program incompatible with other versions of Java. See [It is a bad practice to use Sun's proprietary Java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes)

Comment: @Jesper - Thanks. If you post your comment as an answer then I can accept it. I also thank *nullpointer* for [his/her good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53802790/5318303) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `sun.*` or `com.sun.*` classes in your program; they are undocumented, internal classes of the JDK and can change in any release.

Using them possibly makes your program incompatible with other versions of Java.

See: [It is a bad practice to use Sun's proprietary Java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes)

Comment: Sure in a perfect world, but sometimes you have to do this to get things done.

Comment: @PaulTaylor With the risk that your software will stop working with a new Java version.

Comment: Sure, but these days you usually package your app with a version of Java so you can be sure your app works with the version of java you distribute it with. I would only use sun classes when it is the only way round an issue, its certainly not something I would want to do.

Answer (score 13):

#### It's encapsulated!

The problem wouldn't certainly be solved including all the modules from the JDK.

> I know this package (sun.awt.image) exists in java.desktop module (of
> JDK 11), but don't know how can access it.

The actual crux of the problem here lies in the fact, that even though the class `PNGImageDecoder` and the package it belongs to `sun.awt.image` are a part of the `java.desktop` module, the module has chosen *not to export* it to any external library making use of it.

The choice of abstracting such classes(`sun.*`) has been intentional and documented well with the release notes of Java-9 and the rationale is mentioned in [JEP-260#Encapsulate Most Internal APIs](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260) as well.

---

Having said that, the ***temporary*** rather hacky solution to it would be adding

```
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.image=<yourModuleName>
```

to your command line arguments. Preferably, you should be looking for an alternate way to what you're trying to achieve using the class `PNGImageDecoder`.

---

The last part of it, [*"the unnamed module"*](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module) is where the actual code(be it your application or any dependencies of it) is trying to access this class `PNGImageDecoder`. So think of it like, the command-line arg above for your use-case results in:

```
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: On ubuntu 22.04 I had similar issue with Geoserver using openjdk-18 fix it with small adjustment (no equal sign):  export JAVA_OPTS="--add-exports java.desktop/sun.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED"